# Nexus 7 2013 won't update to 6.x

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-7

On my nexus 7 I have not been able to install any of the 6.0.x updates. Whenever I try I download them and when I go to install half way through my t says error and I restart my tablet and nothing changed. I have tried a reset but it did not change anything. What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to answer my own question as I found a fix. I needed to on the computer download a program to flash my nexus to marshmallow. So I have found a guide and will post how well it works later.
Guide: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#razor

Answer (score 0):

Google has given out an end of life (EOL) policy, which lists different hardware and versions and their final deadline for guaranteed software updates.
You can check if you can find your device listed here:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6220366?hl=en
and see if the EOL time has been reached.
More news on the different Nexus EOL's can be found for e.g. here:
http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/06/21/google-support-site-now-lists-end-life-dates-nexus-devices/

If your device is listed, but the EOL has not been reached, you should still be able to access guaranteed google updates.

Comment: I can access the updates but when installing they just error out.

Comment: Asus Android Nexus 7 (2013) Jul 2017 is what my EOL is

Comment: I am now planning to just flash my nexus manually to marshmallow

Comment: flashing might do the trick if it has been hanging on the updating, yet it seems to be an odd bug that might be worth reporting to google. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful

Comment: I still give you an upvote since that will fix people who get this problem. (I have less then 15 rep on here so it is not public viewed)